# Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$. Let $A=\{a,b\}$ Find each of the following

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$. Let $A=\{a,b\}$ Find each of the following sets:

$Int_{A}(\{a\})$

$Int_{X}(\{a\})$

$Int_{A}(\{c\})$

Can anyone explain how to do these. I was thinking the first two were $\{a\}$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure that you copied the last one correctly?

Comment: Yes I just double checked

Comment: Then you should also give the definition of $Int_S(T)$, because what I would have guessed does not make sense then. You should do that anyway, since these problems probably come directly after the definitions, and therefore it is important to know which of several possible equivalent definitions you use.

Answer (score 1):

if $\text{Int}_A$ ins the interior in induced topology, then since $\{a\}$ in an open set in $(X,{\mathcal T})$ and  $(A,\mathcal T_A)$ the answers of the two first questions are:  $$\text{Int}_A(\{a\})=\text{Int}_X(\{a\})=\{a\}$$
Since $\{c\}$ is not an open set , what you think about the last question answer?